# Sonar violation: "Method may fail to close stream on exception"

Tags: java, exception, inputstream, sonarqube

I have this method:

```
 private void unZipElementsTo(String inputZipFileName, String destPath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        OutputStream out = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        ZipFile zf = null;

        try {
            zf = new ZipFile(inputZipFileName);

            for (Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> em = zf.entries(); em.hasMoreElements();) {
                ZipEntry entry = em.nextElement();
                String targetFile = destPath + FILE_SEPARATOR + entry.toString().replace("/", FILE_SEPARATOR);
                File temp = new File(targetFile);

                if (!temp.getParentFile().exists()) {
                    temp.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                }

                in = zf.getInputStream(entry);

                out = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
                byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                in.close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (out!=null) out.close();
            if (zf!=null) zf.close();
            if (in!=null) in.close();
        }
    }
```

For this method Sonar give me this Violation:

> Bad practice - Method may fail to close stream on exception 
>   unZipElementsTo(String, String) may fail to close stream on exception

But, I don't see any violations there. Maybe, it is just a False-positive ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's right.
The `OutputStream.close()` method can itself throw an exception.
If this happens, e.g. on the 1st line of your `finally{}` block, then the other streams will be left open.

Comment: A good practice is to use a special utility methods to close the streams silently, i.e. either close or swallow the exception as you cannot recover from such exception anyway:

    public static closeSilently(OutputStream os) {
        try { os.close(); } catch(IOException ex){}
    }

Comment: `IOException` on stream close may indicate that file wasn't written to disk. It's much safer to let it propagate than to ignore it silently.

Answer (score 2):

If `out.close()` or `zf.close()` in the `finally` block throw an exception then the other closes won't be executed.

Comment: Could you please provide any recommendations for quick fix?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively if you're using Java 7 or better, you can use the new try-with-resources mechanism, which handles the close for you.  See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html for details on this new mechanism.

Note that try-with-resources also works with multiple objects that are opened and closed and still preserves the guarantee that objects will be closed in the reverse order of their construction.  Quoth that same page:

> Note that the close methods of resources are called in the opposite order of their creation.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid masking an exception with an exception during the close of the streams
It's often recommended to "hide" any io exception in the finally.

To fix use the org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(...)
or guava Closeables.html#closeQuietly(java.io.Closeable)
in the finally close

more on exception handling issues :
http://mestachs.wordpress.com/2012/10/10/through-the-eyes-of-sonar-exception-handling/