# Sonar is showing Bad Practice Method may fail to close stream on exception

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sonar violation: “Method may fail to close stream on exception”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370427/sonar-violation-method-may-fail-to-close-stream-on-exception)

I have a method that uses DataInputStream , code below :

```
DataInputStream in = null;
    ServletOutputStream outStream = null;
    FileInputStream fileIn = null;
    URL searchDirectory;
    try {
      searchDirectory = (java.net.URL) ctx.lookup("file/testHarnessDirectory");

      File file = new File(searchDirectory.getPath(), filename);
      int length = 0;
      outStream = response.getOutputStream();
      response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
      response.setContentLength((int) file.length());

      response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachement; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
      byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[4096];
      fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
      in = new DataInputStream(fileIn);

      while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(byteBuffer)) != -1)) {
        outStream.write(byteBuffer, 0, length);
      }
      outStream.close();
      fileIn.close();
      in.close();
    }
    catch (NamingException e) {
      LOG.error("Exception", e);
      throw new CPSException(ErrorCode.FILE_HANDLING_EXCEPTION, "Could not download File", e);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      LOG.error("Exception", e);
      throw new CPSException(ErrorCode.FILE_HANDLING_EXCEPTION, "Could not submit File", e);
    }
    finally {
      try {
        if (fileIn != null) {
          fileIn.close();
        }
        if (in != null) {
          in.close();
        }
        if (outStream != null) {
          outStream.close();
        }
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Exception", e);
        throw new CPSException(ErrorCode.FILE_HANDLING_EXCEPTION, "Could not submit File", e);}}
```

But Sonar is giving me :  Bad practice - Method may fail to close stream on exception .
I have looked up this post:[Sonar violation: "Method may fail to close stream on exception"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370427/sonar-violation-method-may-fail-to-close-stream-on-exception?answertab=oldest#tab-top), but seemed incomplete to me. I could be wrong. Could anyone let me know, what is the simple way of closing the streams?

Comment: This is not a 'throw'. Exceptions are thrown by the JVM when you execute your program as *object code*. This is a message *displayed* by *Sonar* when it *reviews* your *source code*. Please use the terminology correctly.

Comment: If you're using Java 7, you could use the [*try-with-resources*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to simplify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this section:

```
 try {
    if (fileIn != null) {
      fileIn.close();
    }
    if (in != null) {
      in.close();
    }
    if (outStream != null) {
      outStream.close();
    }
  }
```

and think, what will happen if `fileIn.close()` fails. Other two streams may remain open. Please put them in separate `try-catch` block. e.g.

```
 try {
    if (fileIn != null) {
      fileIn.close();
    }
  }catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.error("Exception: Could not close file stream", e);
    //throw new CPSException(ErrorCode.FILE_HANDLING_EXCEPTION, "Could not close file stream", e);
  }
 try {
    if (in != null) {
      in.close();
    }
  }catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.error("Exception: Could not close in stream"", e);
    //throw new CPSException(ErrorCode.FILE_HANDLING_EXCEPTION, "Could not close in stream", e);
  }
 try {
    if (outStream != null) {
      outStream.close();
    }
  }
  }catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.error("Exception: Could not close out stream", e);
    //throw new CPSException(ErrorCode.FILE_HANDLING_EXCEPTION, "Could not close out stream", e);
  }
```

Comment: If you rethrow every exception that occurs on `close()`, your "fix" changes nothing - it's more or less equivalent to the original. You have to "swallow" the exceptions that occur when `close()`ing, and maybe report one in the end.

Comment: @Yogendra yes , millimoose is right. And I tried that try catch for each close, and it still gives me the critical error in sonar and in addition it also gives me cyclomatic complexity of 11+.

Comment: @millimoose, what exactly do you mean by : _You have to "swallow" the exceptions that occur when close()ing_ , thanks.

Comment: @SindhuKodoor Swallow means more or less "don't rethrow". Make sure they don't appear again. (As things that you swallow rarely do.) As for the cyclomatic complexity, I don't think you can get rid of that without *try-with-resources*. Dealing with resources that require manual disposal is inherently clunky in Java.

Comment: @millimoose: Sorry I didn't notice in hurry and wasn't here. I updated the answer and sommented the trow statements. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @SindhuKodoor I updated the answer. Re-throwing the exception from first catch block will again make it jump the other two blocks.

Comment: FYI, To all, I had a good read on the API of streams, and came across org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils, it has closeQuitely method, that will allow you to close the streams without checking for nulls or exceptions. So, I avoided the unnecessary try{} catch{}...in finally block.